# How to monitor the output as the process runs on a RedHat Linux server?

Tags: rhel, process

You need to run a process on a RedHat Linux server that takes a little while to run.  You want to monitor the output as the process runs but need to guarantee that the process won't terminate if you loose your ssh session. What do you do? (provide specific command syntax as necessary)

Comment: To start with, you do your own homework.

Comment: I got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nohup your-command-here &> output.txt &
tail -f output.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a terminal multiplexer like screen, or the newer [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/). You can start a session, detach, and come back later.